# Webdriver throws Nosuchemelent exception for modal dialog(which is overlay )

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver

I have modal dialog overlayed. and unable to click or find elements on the dialog popup.

I have this code below to find clipAllElement.

```
   clipAllButton = getWait().until(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(clipAllButton));
   clipAllButton.click();
```

If I execute the below javascript it works fine.

```
        /*String str = "jQuery('.mod-featuredtoday-flyout .ft .cta-button').trigger('click')";
        ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript(str);*/
```

but selenium throws nosuchelement exception

I am using FF 21 and Selenium 2.33

did someone see similar issue and knows any workaround

Comment: `Why do people constantly put prose English in code formatting?`

Comment: @hexafraction Your edit didn't completely fix it.  Kavita, is the dialog an element within an HTML IFrame element?

Comment: It can be a race condition, try:   

       clipAllButton = getWait().ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(clipAllButton));

Comment: @Erik M: thanks for your suggestion. Let me try and will update if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If the modal is contained in an `iframe` you will need to switch to the iframe before selecting elements within.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("foo");
```

When you are done with the iframe, switch back to the main document:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```